# Wordpress: Query Year in a Range of years

Tags: wordpress

I have a start_year and a end_year

f.e: Project-Lorem-Ipsum: $start_year=2001, $end_year=2005

and I need to select a certain year  (f.e. $filter_year=2002) and show the posts that are running in this year. 
That means, $filter_year could be $start_year or $end_year or between $start_year and $end_year.

I did this sketch to show maybe better what i need,
thanks for any help!

```
$filter_year=2002;    

$posts = get_posts(array(
'posts_per_page' => -1, 
'post_type'     => 'post',
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'start_year',
        'value'     => $filter_year,
        'compare'   => '???',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'end_year',
        'value'     => $filter_year,
        'compare'   => '???',
    ),
),
```

Comment: is it the post date of the post you are trying to filter by or custom meta fields? if so what are the field names?

Comment: "start_year" and "end_year" are the names of custom meta fields

Comment: David, do you have an idea how to do this? thanks alot!

Comment: well did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta query for this. But there are changes to be made to make these work, if not already implemented.

1: You can use the date type in meta query but it will only work in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime('1/1/15') ); // cant just use the year, it will see it as a time value
$end_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime('31/12/15') ); // cant just use the year, it will see it as a time value

'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND'
    array(
        'key' => 'start_year',
        'value' => $start_date,
        'compare' => '>='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'start_year',
        'value' => $end_date,
        'compare' => '<='
    ),
)
```

2: Convert dates to timestamps (preferred)

```
$start_date = strtotime('1/1/15'); // cant just use the year, it will see it as a time value
$end_date = strtotime('31/12/15'); // cant just use the year, it will see it as a time value

'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND'
    array(
        'key' => 'start_year',
        'value' => $start_date,
        'compare' => '>='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'start_year',
        'value' => $end_date,
        'compare' => '<='
    ),
)
```

You can loop over the meta values using wp_query or get_posts and checking to see if the `get_post_meta($postid, 'start_year', true);` exists.